# How to fix populating React components based on JSON response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs

```
 var prices = [];
      $.getJSON("http://www.asterank.com/api/asterank?query={%22neo%22:{%22$lt%22:%22Y%22},%20%22price%22:{%22$gt%22:100000000}}&limit=1000", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key,value) {
          prices.push(value.price);
        });
      });

var App = React.createClass({
   render() {

   return(
     <div className="app">
       <div>
        {console.log("logging price array")}
        {console.log(this.props.priceData)}
        {this.props.priceData.map(p => <PriceColumn price={p} />)}
       </div>
    </div>
   )
  }
});

var PriceColumn = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return(
    <div>
        <h4>{this.props.price}</h4>
    </div>
    )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<App priceData={prices}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

I'm trying to populate a react component with a json response. This is a short snippet of the console.log of "this.props.priceData"

```
Array[871]
[0 … 99]
0:
525905281.52797025
1:
604514917.0552349
2:
696637551.9520638
3:
875462960.8222823
4:
1267502400
5:
1332894080
6:
1467819274.5386994
7:
1498253120
8:
1703699200
9:
1743786240
10:
1864047360
11:
2725918720
12:
3191380043.7561345
13:
3652885251.1255836
14:
4587566603.506
```

Every time I try to access the data points in this area, I get undefined. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$.getJSON is asynchronous, so your callback has not been executed when you use prices in the React.render method.  A better approach is to make the component itself responsible for the call, and store the returned prices in its state with the callback. E.g.

```
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState() {
     return {
       priceData: []
     }
   },

   componentWillMount() {
     const apiUrl = "http://www.asterank.com/api/asterank?query={%22neo%22:{%22$lt%22:%22Y%22},%20%22price%22:{%22$gt%22:100000000}}&limit=1000";

     $.getJSON(apiUrl, data => {
        this.setState({
           priceData: data.map(item => item.price)
        });
      });    
   },

   render() {
     return(
       <div className="app">
         <div>
           {this.state.priceData.map(p => <PriceColumn price={p} />)}
         </div>
       </div>
     )
  }
});

var PriceColumn = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return(
    <div>
        <h4>{this.props.price}</h4>
    </div>
    )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

On an unrelated note, it is generally unnecessary to use JQuery within a React application.  If you are only using it for your AJAX calls, then you can either use the [browser fetch api](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) with a polyfill for unsupported browsers, or a much more lightweight library, such as Axios.

Comment: need to use getIntialState method, constructor is es6 class syntax method

Comment: awesome, that makes total sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is the React component doesnt render when your data is received, it only renders when ReactDOM.render is called and prices is an empty array at that time

so do this

```
// you can use promises too instead of simply a callback argument
fetchPrices(callback) {
  $.getJSON("<api_endpoint>", function(data) {
    var result = Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
      return data[key].price;
    });

    callback(result);
  });
}

var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
     return { prices: [] };
   },
   componentDidMount() {
     fetchPrices(function(result) {
       this.setState({ prices: result });
     });
   },
   render() {
     return (
       <div className="app">
         <div>
           {this.props.priceData.map(p => <PriceColumn price={p} />)}
         </div>
       </div>
     );
   }
});

var PriceColumn = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return(
    <div>
        <h4>{this.props.price}</h4>
    </div>
    )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<App priceData={prices}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: This helped me understand the concept more, I really appreciate it.